# pegar valor de variável javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Olá! Preciso pegar o valor de uma variável javascript, postar para uma página php pra criar uma variável session php.
aqui tento passaar a variável js:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var valor = "";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:radio[name=aviso]').click(function() {

            //Executa Loop entre todas as Radio buttons com o name de valor
            $('input:radio[name=aviso]').each(function() {
                //Verifica qual está selecionado
                if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                    valor = parseInt($(this).val());
            })

            alert(valor);
            $.post( "cria_session.php", { aviso: valor} );
        })
    })
</script>
```

Aqui tento, ao menos, imprimir na tela:

```
<?            
        echo "Olá <script>document.write(valor)</script>"?>
```

Só o que funciona é o alert(valor);

Alguém sabe?

Comment: Vc vai pegar o valor no PHP com `$_POST['aviso']`

Comment: Já tentei assim. Mas não exibiu nada!

Comment: Não irá exibir nada mesmo, porque o PHP será executado no servidor quando o Ajax fizar a requisição. A não ser que vc utilize um callback para algum propósito.

Comment: No javascript, tenta dar uns `console.log(valor);` e ver se a variável possui alguma informação.

Comment: Marcelo Martins, possui sim. Está sendo exibido corretamente no alert(valor);

Comment: Então... Dentro do script js está tudo ok. Só não está enviando o valor pro PHP!

Comment: Como vc sabe que não está enviando?

Comment: Porque eu mando imprimir $_POST['aviso']

Answer (score 1):

É importante saber que uma das características do JavaScript são os CallBacks. (https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced)

Assim, ao enviares a variável para o ficheiro cria_session.php, podes criar a sessão com o valor que envias-te, e no final fazer o retorno desse valor que será mostrado no CallBack da função que envia os valores. Exemplo do ficheiro cria_session.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$valor = $_POST['aviso'];
$_SESSION['aviso'] = $valor;

echo $valor;
```

No javascript, no callback do $.post fazes o alert da variável. Exemplo:

```
$.post("cria_session.php", {aviso: valor}, function(result){
    alert(result);
  });
```

Comment: O `return` do PHP no Ajax não faz nenhum efeito. Teria que ser `echo`.

Comment: Como não faz efeito nenhum ? Retorna variáveis, objectos, o que quiseres. E com isso fazes o que quiseres no callback do post.

Comment: O return só vai funcionar lá no PHP, não manda nada de volta pro Ajax. Ou seja, o `result` do callback virá vazio.

Comment: Tens razão, mas fazendo print da variável o result já vem preenchido.

Comment: Não. O PHP continua vazio, apesar de o javascrip recuperar o valor e só dentro do script. Em outros lugares da página não imprime.

Comment: @RubensSgarbiAyres tens de explicar melhor o que é que queres fazer e qual a tua ideia.. A tua pergunta era pegar numa variável JS, enviar para um ficheiro PHP e criar uma sessão, isso está respondido. Não sabemos o propósito da tua aplicação e o que queres fazer concretamente com essa variável para te ajudarmos.

Comment: Está respondido, mas não funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Moçada,
 consegui aqui. Mudei o final do script. Ficou assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function() {
          $('input:radio[name=aviso]').click(function() {
            var valor = "";
                 //Executa Loop entre todas as Radio buttons com o name de valor
                 $('input:radio[name=aviso]').each(function() {
                     //Verifica qual está selecionado
                     if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                         valor = parseInt($(this).val());

                 })

                 alert(valor);
                 //document.write(valor);
                 $.post("cria_session.php", {
                    aviso : valor}, function(msg){
                    $("#resultado").html(msg);
```

})

```
             })
         })

     </script>
```